# Systems with a finite number of linearly independent states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-states

I am studying systems that admit only a finite number of linearly independent states. In such a case, $|S(t)>$ lives in a N-dimensional vector space and can be represented by a column of N components with respect to a given basis, and operators take the form of ordinary (N x N) matrices. For instance, the Hamiltonian in a two-state system can take the following form:

$$H = \begin{pmatrix}h&g\\g&h\ \end{pmatrix}$$

And the two states of the system are:

$$|1> = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

$$|2> = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

The typical issue in these cases is to claim that the system at $|S(0)>$ has a state, let's say:

$$|S(0)> = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

And ask for the state of the system at $|S(t)>$ (see Griffiths, ending of the formalism's chapter).

I am OK at this point but I began thinking about **what would happen if we included another operator into the problem**.

My thought is that **the only condition for being able to play with the second operator at the state** $|S(t)>$ **is that the eigenvectors of both operators can be written as a linear combination of the two states of the system.**

**But I suspect that it cannot be just that; the commutation relations may play a role as well.** But sometimes we are given matrices (which represent operators) without specifying what kind of operator is. In these cases you cannot use commutation relations because you do not know about the *nature* of your second operator (i.e you do not know if it is momentum, position...).

Please let me know if I am wrong and what I am missing here.

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by "including" and "playing with" a second operator? And for that matter, what does it mean to "play with an operator at a state"? Are you thinking of an operator whose action is not well-defined in a particular region of Hilbert space?

Comment: Note: if you have matrix representations of two operators, you can immediately find their commutator. You don't need to know what "type" of operators they are.

Comment: @probably_someone I will try to clarify myself: Imagine I am given another 2 x 2 operator and I want, for instance, calculate the probability of a measurement gives one of the eigenvalues of my second operator. Before doing so I need that both operators commute isn't it?

Comment: Is that connected somehow with the fact that the eigenvectors of both operators can be written as a linear combination of the two states of the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an $n$-dimensional Hilbert space, any $n\times n$ matrix can in principle be a representation of an operator on this space. Whether that operator corresponds to an *observable* is a different story; in particular, matrices that represent operators corresponding to the measurement of observable quantities must have *real eigenvalues*, which is equivalent to the operator being self-adjoint (and for finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, is also equivalent to the matrix being Hermitian). Examples of operators that do *not* correspond to observables are the raising and lowering operators of the simple harmonic oscillator. Neither of these are self-adjoint; the adjoint of the raising operator is the lowering operator.

In any case, the commutator of two operators has nothing to do with the "nature" of the operator, whatever that's supposed to mean. For any two matrices $A$, $B$, the commutator of $A$ and $B$ is defined as $[A,B]=AB-BA$. If you have the matrix representation of both operators, then you can compute the commutator.

To answer the questions in your comments: if you have a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ that represents an operator that corresponds to the measurement of an observable, then $A$ must be Hermitian. Suppose the eigenstates of $A$ are $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$, with (real) eigenvalues $r$ and $s$, respectively. The probability that the state $|S(t)\rangle$ will be measured to be in state $|a\rangle$, and thus will be measured to have value $r$ for the observable, is $|\langle a|S(t)\rangle|^2$, and likewise for state $|b\rangle$ an observable value $s$.

*Any* two non-equivalent states (meaning any two states $|a\rangle$, $|b\rangle$ such that $|a\rangle\neq c|b\rangle$ for any real $c$) span a $2$-dimensional Hilbert space. This is a basic fact of vector spaces. As such, *any* state is a linear combination of two non-equivalent states.

Comment: Thanks your answer is helpful, but I still do not know why when we have the state at time t as a linear combination of the two eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian, we are able to use the eigenvectors of *another operator* called O (which is an observable, as well as the hamiltonian) in the same state $|S(t)>$. My guess was that it is possible because *the eigenvectors of both operators can be written as a linear combination of the two states of the system*. But as you said: 'any state is a linear combination of two non-equivalent states'.

Comment: Does this mean that we can do this with any observable? Sorry for insisting on this but I really want to understand it.

Comment: @JD_PM I think I understand what you're trying to say now. You want to know why we can decompose the state vector $|S(t)\rangle$ as a linear combination of either the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian or as a linear combination of the eigenvectors of another operator. This is only true if the operator is diagonalizable (i.e. none of its eigenvalues are zero). If the operator is diagonalizable, then its eigenvectors form what is called a _basis_ of the vector space (the Hilbert space is a vector space).

Comment: @JD_PM A basis should be a familiar concept from any linear algebra textbook. It's essentially a minimal set of vectors such that _any other vector_ can be decomposed as a linear combination of the vectors in the set. There's nothing particularly special about the eigenvectors in this sense, and in this case, _any_ two non-collinear vectors form a basis. An example of an operator whose eigenvectors do _not_ form a basis is a projection operator, like $P=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. The only eigenvector of this operator is $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Oh so the condition is that the operator O has to be diagonalizable! So what you mean is that we will always get as eigenvectors of the observable O something like this: $a \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $b \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

Comment: Where $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ are the two states of the system.

Comment: @JD_PM When $O$ is diagonalized, yes, that's exactly what will happen. Note that $O$ and $H$ may not necessarily be simultaneously diagonalizable; if they aren't, then the eigenstates of $O$ are not energy eigenstates.

Comment: Oh so that means that the condition for $O$ having energy eigenstates is that both $H$ and $O$ must commute!